# How can I add a wildcard to have all links that contains : "food" as trusted site in uBlock Origin?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, wildcards, ublock-origin

First time using wild cards.
How can I include all links that contain a specific word, For example,
I tried typing.

```c
*food*
```

uBlock does not recognize this line as shown in the image below, it highlights it with red:
[image: ublock does not recognize food]

I tried typing:

```c
*food*
```

uBlock does not recognize this line.
I expected it to trust every site that contains:

```c
*food*
```

Comment: What about `.+food?.+`?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio It did not work:(

Answer (score 2):

As [per documentation](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/How-to-mark-a-web-site-as-trusted#regular-expression), you can use a regular expression when nothing else work:

> When you are facing a case where no other directive syntax work, you may use a regular expression ("regex") as a last resort solution. When a trusted site directive starts and ends with a forward slash (`/`), uBO will treat the directive as a regex-based one.

So in your case, the following should work:

```
/food/
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I include all links that contain a specific word?

You can't.

> All trusted site directives are matched against the URL address of web pages.
>
> As of version uBlock Origin (uBO) 0.8.2.0, the trusted site directive
> syntax is split into three classes:
>
> - Plain
> - Complex
> - Comment
>
> Plain syntax is when using only hostname label(s), which means only
> the hostname portion of a URL will be taken into account. With plain
> syntax, the matching is performed by comparing the right-most portion
> of the page hostname with the trusted site directive. **Wildcards are
> not allowed when using plain syntax**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [How to mark a web site as trusted · gorhill/uBlock Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/How-to-mark-a-web-site-as-trusted#regular-expression)